# Changing Text based on Year in Tableau

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I'm very new to Tableau and I have created a map dashboard for missing persons incidence with a year filter. I wanted to create the map in a way that as the year changes, my dashboard would display a certain text. I googled around and saw it might be possible by creating parameter, but I'm not sure.

Example of what I want:

So let's say when I toggle through the filter and have year 2011, I want a title or text somewhere else displaying "Afghanistan the highest", and when I go to 2012, then the text changes to "Syria had a tumultuous year". How can I do that in Tableau?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Take saperate sheet and Create a calculated field and write below formula

```
IF WINDOW_MAX(SUM([Sales])) = SUM([Sales])
THEN ATTR([state]) + " "+ "the Highest"
END
```

Here set the compute to table down.

Now in dashboard combine both the sheets, No need of parameter fields in this method

You need to play a bit with formatting options to show only highest country in one sheet and all countries in other sheet